# Does anyone know how to maximize enchantment level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've surrounded my enchantment table with bookshelves, but the levels won't go anywhere above 30

Comment: 30 is the highest level... You've already maximized the enchantment level.

Answer (score 0):

30 Is the highest level that you can get in survival minecraft.  If you want to cheat you can do /enchant @p  
(While holding said item) Then you can enchant it as high as you want.  (If cheats are enabled)